# How to configure Info.plist file in ejected react-native app uses expo sdk

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, account-kit, native-module

i created an app using `react-native ini projectName` and i added a native module package called `react-native-facebook-account-kit`
And i need to change Info.plist in ios folder and add app id and client token info. Also i created a pod file as facebook docs said.
It works fine. Then i tried to make exactly same thing in expo.
So i used this cli to create a new project 
`create-react-native-app projectName` then i run `npm run eject` and selected second option which is uses both react-native and expo sdk.
So it created ios and android folders successfully.

BUT in ios folder there is no Info.plist file. After my search i found this doc.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration#ios
And i added some key and values into `app.json` like doc said.

```
    {
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "27.0.0",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.cecil.foxtail",
      "infoPlist": {
        "FacebookAppID": "myAppId",
        "AccountKitClientToken": "myClientToken",
        "CFBundleURLTypes": [
          // ??? CONFUSED
        ]
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.cecil.foxtail"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the original Info.plist from the app which is working great.

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
  <string>{app-id}</string>
  <key>AccountKitClientToken</key>
  <string>{client-token}</string>
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>ak{client-token}</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

So how to define these array into app.json ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set a custom URL Schema because expo by default sets it to your **bundleIdentifier**

> "bundleIdentifier": "com.cecil.foxtail",

So you can call your app from another by calling something like this:-

```
let websiteUrl ="https://apps.apple.com/myappInstallationPage";
let SchemaUrl = 'com.cecil.foxtail://';
Linking.canOpenURL(SchemaUrl).then(supported => {
    if (supported) {
        console.log('accepted');
        return Linking.openURL(SchemaUrl);
    } else {
        console.log('an error occurred');
    }
}).catch(err => {
    Linking.openURL(websiteUrl).catch(reason => console.log('Failed to open app website!'))
    console.log('an error occurred')
});
```

Hope it helps.